# Piping awk output into grep

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

So I'm writing a bash script to alphabetically list names from a text file, but only names with the same frequency (defined in the second column)

```
grep -wi '$1' /usr/local/linuxgym-data/census/femalenames.txt |
awk '{ print ($2) }' |
grep '$1' /usr/local/linuxgym-data/census/femalenames.txt |
sort |
awk '{ print ($1) }'
```

Since I'm doing this for class, I've been given the example of inputting 'ANA', and should return

```
ANA

RENEE
```

And the document has about 4500 lines in it

but the two fields I'm looking at have

```
ANA            0.120     55.989    181

RENEE          0.120     56.109    182
```

And so I want to find all names with the second column the same as ANA (0.120). The second column is the frequency of the name... This is just dummy data given to me by my school, so I don't know what that means.
But if there was another name with the same frequency as ANA (0.120) it would also be listed in the output.

When I run the commands on their own, they work fine, but it seems to have trouble with the 3rd line with using the awk output as $1 in the grep below it.

I am pretty new to this, so I'm most likely doing it in the most roundabout way.

Comment: Show us your input file and show us what do you expected out of it, _rather_ than stating why your code doesn't work!

Comment: Good point

Well, since I'm doing this for class, I've been given the example of inputting 'ANA', and should return
ANA
RENEE

And the document has about 4500 lines in it

but the two fields I'm looking at have
ANA            0.120 55.989    181   and on the next line  

RENEE          0.120 56.109    182

Comment: Update the input file in question and _not_ in comments section

Comment: Can you clarify further? Is RENEE gonna be always part of the output? How is ANNA related to RENNE?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  Am MCVE also shows how you call/execute your code, e.g. what is $1?
Have you tried looking at the output of each step of your pipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With single ***awk***:

```
inp="ANA"
awk -v inp=$inp '{ a[$1]=$2 } END { if(inp in a){ v=a[inp]; 
       for(i in a){ if(a[i]==v) print i }}
}' /usr/local/linuxgym-data/census/femalenames.txt | sort
```

The output:

```
ANA
RENEE
```

---

- `a[$1]=$2` - accumulating *frequency* value for each *name*
- `if(inp in a){ v=a[inp];` - if the input *name* `inp` is in array - get its *frequency* value
- `for(i in a){ if(a[i]==v) print i` - print all *names* that have the same frequency value as for input *name*

Comment: Worked great
I just changed inp="ANA"  to  inp="$1"
and added   "| sort"  to the end of the last line

Comment: @Astrobama, ok, I've added `sort` at the end

Comment: Why don't you just compare to `a[inp]` instead of creating `v`.

Comment: @123, if I remove `if(inp in a){ v=a[inp];` and there would not be the line with `ANA` but the line like `RENEE 0 56.109 182` is presented - then your supposition would return RENEE while it shouldn't

Comment: You can still check if it is populated without the redundant variable. `if(inp in a)for(i in a){ if(a[i]==a[inp]) print i }`

Comment: @123, you didn't get it: "we are saving reference to the array value into variable to avoid multiple accessing the array value by key (moreover, at the same time the array is traversed)". On the other hand, I can accept your "shortening" for small files

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do this in one line, but that's a pushing it a bit. Split it into two pieces to make it easier to write/read. For example:

```
name=$1
src=/usr/local/linuxgym-data/census/femalenames.txt

# get the frequency you're after
freq=$(awk -v name="$name" '$1==name {print $2}' "$src")

# get the names with that frequency
awk -v freq="$freq" '$2==freq {print $1}' "$src"
```

Tradeoff between this and RomanPerekhrest's solution is that their solution will do one scan, but index everything in memory. This one will scan the file twice, but save you the memory.

Comment: Passing shell variables to awk through string interpolation is a bad idea, use the syntax `awk -v avar="$svar" ...`

Answer (score 0):

This should probably do it...

```
f="/usr/local/linuxgym-data/census/femalenames.txt"
grep $(grep -wi -m 1 "$1" $f | awk '{ print ($2) }') $f | \
  sort | awk '{ print ($1) }'
```

Test...

```
echo 'ANA            0.120     55.989    181
RENEE          0.120     56.109    182' > fem
foo() { grep $(grep -wi -m 1 "$1" $f | awk '{ print ($2) }') $f | \
         sort | awk '{ print ($1) }' ; }
f=fem ; foo ANA
```

Output:

```
ANA
RENEE
```